# How do I create a shortcut to Gnome 3 Activities menu?

Tags: shortcuts, ubuntu-gnome, activities-overview

I created ~/.local/share/applications/bt.desktop file containing entry

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=btsync
Exec==~/Progs/btsync
Icon=un-reboot.png
Type=Application
Terminal=true;
```

Command ~/Progs/btsync works and btsync runs. How do I add this to Activities menu to be just clicked?

Comment: did you tried to lock to launcher while app running

Comment: App runs on the background, no visible icon when running.

Comment: You have error there `Exec==` should be `Exec=`. Also use full path , `~` is not understood by `.desktop` files . `Terminal=true` does not need semicolon

Comment: I will post it as an answer then

Comment: Ah, you already posted your own. Well, nevermind then :)

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct entry with correct syntax:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=btsync
Exec=/home/ohto/Progs/btsync
Icon=un-reboot.png
Type=Application
Terminal=true
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create the relevant desktop entry in `~/.local/share/applications`. Your entry already contains necessary information, although I also recommend you to add an icon.

Comment: FIle is in the location you mention. I added the icon. Ran Alt+F2 and r to reload Gnome. No luck.